# How to overwrite get method in Django Rest Framework's API View

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build an API View that returns some data from my database depending on what I send as a request.

I have a model BuildingGroup that has many buildings which have many cool and heat objects. These heat and cool objects have a year and a value. When I send a specific year I want to list all of the heat/cool values of that year in that BuildingGroup.

I think it should be simple, but I don't know if I am going into the right direction.

I am trying to overwrite the get method of Django's APIView like so:

```
class BuildingGroupYearHeatObjects(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk):
        data = request.data
        year = request.data['year']

        ...here should go more code.....        

        return Response(year)
```

I get a key error here: `KeyError: 'year'`

My url

```
    path('demand/heat/<int:pk>/',BuildingGroupYearHeatObjects.as_view(),
```

my request:

```
def test_api_local(method='post', data={}):

    payload = {
        'id' : '1',
        'year' : 2022
    }

    r = requests.request(method, APP_ENDPOINT , json=payload)
    print(r.text)

    return r


test_api_local(method='get', data={ 'id' : 1,
                                 'year' : 2022})
```

So my question is if I actually going the right way and also why do I get a key error? I only get the key error when I refresh the API view in the browser. But if I send a request I don't get it. I guess it is because I am not sending a year when I refresh the browser?

But how could I solve this?

Also if someone could lead me to how I could implement listing the heat/cool objects following the sent year?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Here are my models:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)


class BuildingGroup(models.Model):
    description           = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    buildings             = models.ManyToManyField(Building, default=None, blank=True)


class DemandBase(models.Model):
    year            = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=default_year())
    demand          = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    building        = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

(DemandBase has two subclasses DemandHeat and DemandCool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `KeyError` exception because you're trying to access the data dictionary of the request which is used when you do `post`, `put`, `patch` requests.

You are making `get` request so you cannot send a body in your request. You can use query url parameter and then access if via `query_params` of your request in the code.

But I would suggest you to use filtering and you would not need to write any complicated code yourself.

You simply write your view, use a rest framework's generics`ListAPIView`. You specify your queryset and serializer.

And then look at the `django-filter` package ( https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

You can easily add a filter for the `year` and it will apply the filter on your queryset to select only objects for selected year.